How to convert bits from python to php?
I have this hex code F0C2CA89012A04008C0000000000000000000000 from the device. This hex code shows the value of the water drops.
In my python code
msg = F0C2CA89012A04008C0000000000000000000000
msg_counters = bytes.fromhex(msg)[5:20] 
# output: b'*\x04\x00\x8c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'      
msg_counters_int = int.from_bytes(msg_counters)
# output: 218157641024778742068286256301735936    
bin_string = '{:0120b}'.format(msg_counters_int)
print(bin_string)

this print the value of bits. These bits shows the value of water
001010100000010000000000100011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

00101 = 5
01000 = 8
00010 = 2

I'm trying to convert the code to PHP and I'm stuck in int.from_bytes from python. I don't know how to convert the value.
In my PHP code
$a = hex2bin("F0C2CA89012A04008C0000000000000000000000");
$b = substr($a, 5, 20);
// output: b"*\x04\x00Œ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"

I tried to use unpack functionality but it doesn't show the correct value

NameError: name 'F0C2CA89012A04008C0000000000000000000000' is not defined  - please provide valid code.

Here is an alternative solution that doesn't rely on the GMP extension, but on the standard base_convert() function. For every byte, the two hex digits are extracted from the input string and converted to base 2:
function getBits(string $msg, int $from, int $to)
{
    $bits = '';
    for($i=$from; $i<$to; $i++)
    {
        $s = base_convert(substr($msg, 2*$i, 2), 16, 2);
        $bits .= str_pad($s, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $bits;
}

echo getBits('F0C2CA89012A04008C0000000000000000000000', 5, 20);

Output:
001010100000010000000000100011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

